# Is it permitted to use perfumes while fasting?

Tags: halal-haram, sawm, perfume

I heard that it is makrooh to use perfumes in ramadan.

Did the prophet (PBUH) allow us to use perfumes (without alcohol) during fasting in Ramadan?

Please post some hadiths regarding this.

Comment: A hadith on this purpose would be hard to find as it's a matter of ijtihad as if there was a hadith or a Verse of Quran there would be consensus about it. Maliki school say it's makruh but others say no or even it's mustahab

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The scholars of the Standing Committee for Issuing Fatwas were asked:

*Can the fasting person wear perfume?*

> They replied: He may put perfume on his clothes or on that which he wears on his head or body. **But he should not put it in his nose.**
>
> Fataawa al-Lajnah al-Daa’imah (10/328).

Source: http://islamqa.info/en/ref/108014

This is because one of the things that nullifies the fast is inhaling or putting some kind of smoke or dust into the throat. No harm in simply patting it on the body.

Answer (score 5):

(Shia View)

Based on this hadith from [Imam Ja'far al-Sadiq](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ja%27far_al-Sadiq) (AS) not only it's not makruh, but also it's mustahabb (recommended):

> الطیب تحفة الصائم
>
> Perfume is the masterpiece of the fasted.

Source: [Man la yahduruhu al-Faqih](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man_la_yahduruhu_al-Faqih) translated by Ghaffari et al, volume 2, page 442